# Nifi notify/wait to notify another processor chain after finished ftp download

Tags: ftp, apache-nifi, dataflow

[image: Nifi Structure]

I am trying to get a dataflow from an ftp server that is structured like this:
FolderA -> File1, File2, ... File28
​FolderB -> File1, File2, ... File28
​FolderC -> File1, File2, ... File28
​
​These files are regularly updated every 2 hours one by one. Every 2 hours after all downloads are done I want to write a flagfile that its actually finished. If not all were updated in time but at least one (i.E. after 10 minutes) I still want to write a flagfile which is taken up by other process chains that then have to deal with missing data. Each folder needs a flag file: FolderA.flag, FolderB.flag....

The problem is I kinda don't quite understand how notify and wait really works. I want to put a new Flowfile into wait as soon as the first file in a folder is updated. Therefore I put an attribute into the files on the right side called "FolderName". If I connect the wait node to success of the new attribute I get 28 files for each folder into the wait queue. But I only want one. Thats why I generate a new flowfile on the ride side (I actually would like to have that node eliminated if possible and the wait node connected to the right hand chain because I do not know which folders are on the server)

The "Release Signal Identifier" is set to "FolderName" in both notify and wait. I do not know what to set for "Signal Counter Name" and well it does not work as I would like it to.
Current behaviour is that each time that GenerateFlowFile is triggered the wait node does not really wait but directly moves on and triggers the flag file after I had one successfull run on the right hand side. Do I have to reset the trigger count (Is it not "consumed"?)
How to connect both sides correctly?

[image]

This is a picture of my cache after one folder ran through. Why is there 28 times the entry instead of just once with the latest count? This also does trigger the wait node. (Note: I currently for testing have it specified to name the wait/notify trigger exactly FolderName and only take actually one specific folder in ListFTP to get the debugging better)
But the wait node is now always triggered. As the cached entity is not expired or removed. I guess I have to remove it manually?